# SQLite Exception : no such column

Tags: java, android, database

Hi everyone i have a query for update table...but i receive an error that say no such column
this is my java code :

```
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE "+TABLE_CONTACTS +" SET booksAmanat = " +jsonArrayString+ " WHERE 
    PersonId="+contact.getId());
```

the column exist in database
and this is error :

```
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: {"id":206406,"name":"1","author":"1"} 
    (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE tbl_contacts SET PersonId = 
    [{"id":206406,"name":"1","author":"1"}] WHERE PersonId=9984744
```

Comment: why don't you use RoomDatabase , It will make your work a lot easier.

Comment: I'm junior , i need to learn base code and will using room

Comment: The exception provided by you says that you don't have that column in the database... which you are trying to update .

Comment: but exist in database

Comment: Person id =9984744 is not available I think so ... which you are trying to set a new value.     and room database is quite easier you can also setup and use it... don;t think that you are junior so you can't\

Comment: Ok my friend maybe this is last way...Thank you so much

Comment: problem solved?

Comment: i wanna use room library

Comment: Nice watch tutorial or blog you will get it and if you face any problem , we are here to help you out.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are trying to update a column's value with a string/text without providing the correct format.

You have to single quote (') the jsonArrayString on both sides in order to be recognized as a text value. You should always wrap your text values with single quotes in SQL queries.

Specifically:
'[{"id":206406,"name":"1","author":"1"}]'

Although, hardcoding your queries is a bad practice that you should always avoid. Your queries are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. This can be easily avoided by binding the parameters.

For example, instead of execSQL you can use the update method of SQLiteDatabase.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase DATABASE_VERSION. If it is 1, make it 2

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```